# Hide a link in the datatable when form is submitted in the popup

Tags: jquery, struts2, datatable, datatables

I need to hide a link in the datatable when the form is submitted in a popup. I have Approve link in the datatable. They are displayed only for particular rows(for batchInfo rows). when I click the link a popup opens and when I am done with the form submitting in the popup, I want the link to disappear(Hide it).

script inside the datatable:

```
<s:if test="%{(batchInfo)}">
<td align="center" onclick="openapproverejectfile('<s:propertyvalue="#approvalURL"/>')">
<a id="ApproveRejectCPlink" href="#"><u>Approve</u></a>
</td>
</s:if>
<s:else>
<td></td>
</s:else>
```

My data table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
searchresults = $("#searchclientfileresults").dataTable({
"sScrollX" : "100%",
"sScrollY":"220px",
"bSort":true,
"bAutoWidth" : false,
"bPaginate" : true,
"aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"]],
"sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
"bLengthChange" : true,
"bFilter" : true,
"bInfo" : false,
"oLanguage": {
"sEmptyTable":   "No data available in table"
},
"aoColumns": [
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null
]
});
});
```

How do I hide the link on form submit in some popup inside a datatable??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#searchclientfileresults tr').click(function (event) { 
$('#searchclientfileresults tr').data('clicked', true); //select the row clicked in datatable 
}); });
```

with this we can select the row of the link dynamically.